# Working with streams on WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I make a quick start on `Windows Phone 7` in working with `streams`?

I need to be able to load from disk, save to disk, load from Memory,save to memory a file on `wp7`, but everytime i try to save on this this happens :

```
Silverlight is in a sandboxed mode where it has restricted access. You can write to "Isolated Storage", but you cannot create files on their hard drive.
```

Can you please provide some working examples in working with streams?
Also some tutorials/ video would be nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On WP7 you can only use Isolated Storage to save/read files. You can find many tutorials about it, like on MSDN [Isolated Storage Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) or this one: [All about WP7 Isolated Storage – intro to Isolated Storage](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage). Check other parts of that to read about saving/reading data from Isolated Storage using streams.

Comment: No, there isn't. That's how WP7 is designed.

Comment: Could you please provide some more links for tutorials/articles?